# Qt - ERROR: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MainWindow’ with no type

Tags: qt, qt-creator

First of all, i posted the question after a lot of searching, reading and debugging ... but can't solve the problem.

I have two class MainWindow and Controller, both of them need to include the other. I tried to solve the problem of recursive include using forwarding, but it didn't work.
I think i have some problem with implementing forward with namespaces.

The code for both classes: (i tried to shorten the code as much as possible)

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include "controller.h"


namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void addRadioButtons();
    void changeViewQML(QString);
    void changeViewXML(QString);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    controller controllerObj;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**controller.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QtCore>
#include "mainwindow.h"


class controller : public QThread
{
public:
    controller();
    void response_handler(QString);

private:
    MainWindow *viewObj;

protected:
    void run();

};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"   

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeViewQML(QString s)
{
    qDebug(s.toAscii());
}
```

**controller.cpp**

```
#include "controller.h"

controller::controller()
{
}

void controller::response_handler(QString responseFilePath)
{
    viewObj->changeViewQML(responseFilePath);
}
```

and i keep having this ISO error.

sorry for the long code, and if any part is not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just forward declare the `MainWindow`. Replace 
`#include "mainwindow.h"` in the controller.h

with

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}
```

also refer to it as `Ui::MainWindow *viewObj;` or write `using namespace Ui` in your controller.h

**EDIT**

this compiles fine:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include "controller.h"

namespace Ui{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void addRadioButtons();
    void changeViewQML(QString);
    void changeViewXML(QString);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    controller controllerObj;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**controller.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QtCore>
//#include "mainwindow.h"
class MainWindow;


class controller : public QThread
{
public:
    controller();
    void response_handler(QString);

private:
    MainWindow *viewObj;

protected:
    void run();

};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeViewQML(QString s)
{
    qDebug(s.toAscii());
}
```

**controller.cpp**

```
#include "controller.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

controller::controller()
{
}

void controller::run()
{
}

void controller::response_handler(QString responseFilePath)
{
    viewObj->changeViewQML(responseFilePath);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, it gives me error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Ui::MainWindow’ ... i tried to solve this new error my #include "mainwindow.h" in the controller.cpp file but it don work !!!

Comment: ok, sorry I was confused by the fact that `MainWindow` and `Ui::MainWindow` are 2 different classes, I'm going to edit my answer with a working example

Comment: when i tried your solution, i found that the file "ui_mainwindow.h" that mainview.cpp includes has this code: namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui
.... BTW the mainview class is auto-generated by QtCreator

Comment: It worked correctly, although tried your solution before ... but i think i was doing some wrong with the changes i have been making ... ThanQ for the help